# Changing the justification of legend symbol text set from "set labels from expression..." in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend, text

In QGIS, I have a polygon layer with several text column attributes. I am theming on one, but want the text of another column to show up in the legend. I have successfully populated the text column using the "set labels from Expression..." dialogue from the layer properties legend window as per image1...

[image]

But in the actual legend in layout view, the text only shows up as center justified and there is no apparent way to set it to left justify, so that it does not overlap with the symbols (image2).

[image]

I've tried changing the text alignment attributes in the layout-legend-Fonts and text panel, but none of the four options there affect the text attribute column independently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `legend tab → Text on Symbol`, you need to select the column that holds the lithology symbols, not the description (Lithology), and everything should work correctly:

- Select label from expression and select the column in the attribute table that holds the symbols (code) of the lithology:

[image]

- The lithology description should be loaded automatically when you style your layer based on the description column.:

[image]

- Here is the output:

[image]

- In the layout view, here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. That definitely works the way I hoped it would.  Except that retheming on Lithology instead of Code resets all 250+ colours to new random assortment.  I wonder if there is an elegant way to transfer the code-themed colours to the new Lithology-themed layer?

Comment: @JarrodBrown I am not aware of any way or tool that can help you to transfer the code-themed colors to the new Lithology-themed layer.